# Remove Selected Table Row in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

May I know how to remove table row for selected row only. For example, If I choose 2 rows to delete, it will delete the chosen rows. I have made this example but I do not know how to get the id's of the chosen row. Below are the example,

**jQuery:**

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
        var del = $("#delete").val();
        var cb=[];
        $('.checkBox:checked').each(function(){
            cb.push($(this).val()); // id's of selected checkbox to delete
        });
        $.post('delete-pr.php',
        {
            del : del,
            cb : cb
        }, function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            $('#myTable tr:last').remove(); // this will delete last row only
        });  
});
```

**html:**

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAll" title="Select All"></th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Type of Purchase</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM purchase";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $pr_id=$row['pr_id'];
?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" id="checkBox" class="checkBox" value="<?php echo $row['pr_id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['purchase_type']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    } 
} 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: want to remove multiple row or single ?

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context. Now would be enough: `$('#myTable tr:has(.checkBox:checked)').remove();`

Comment: $('.checkBox:checked').each(function(){
            $(this).parents('tr').remove(0);
        });
in sucess

Comment: @Poria `remove(0)`? Is that just a typo?

Comment: @A.Wolff  yes and both with 0 and without 0 does the same

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff your answer solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add after the success message

```
function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
    $('.checkBox:checked').each(function(){
       $(this).parent('tr').remove() ; // id's of selected checkbox to delete
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need each loop here :)

Comment: I think yes - your answer is also fine here.

Comment: Thanks. Found this helpful.